# Why does document.open() fail silenty in a FireFox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

If I have the following code in a content script (content.js):

```
document.open();
document.write('test');
document.close();
```

With a minimal manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "tabs", "storage"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

The browser should display nothing other than 'test' - but this only works in Chrome. The exact same code doesn't work in FireFox, with no console errors, and if I add a `console.log()` after the above code, it never fires.

If I paste the exact same code in to the console on FireFox (or Chrome) it works as expected, but it just doesn't work from a content script.

I have also tried changing `document` for `window.top.document` and similar, and I've output the `document` object to ensure I'm not going crazy (and it is valid), so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

**Update:** I have also discovered that if you run `document.write();` in the console to get a blank page, and then reload the plugin in `about:debugging`, then the plugin runs again and works - but only if I run `open` or `write` from the console manually first.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I have made some edits and added a minimal manifest, but the question is fairly complete in itself - why does document.open/write/close not work in a FF content script (with no errors), but it does in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works, but in case anyone else comes across this specific issue, calling the following doesn't work (fails silently, and no further execution).

```
document.write('test');
```

Whereas this works fine:

```
window.eval('document.write()');
document.write('test')
```